# while creating csv file, the file has extra records in controller

Tags: java

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=download.csv");

sb = Dataretriver.generateCsvFileBuffer(Fields,fieldsForm.getRowNum());

System.out.println("--this will generates csv file format");

InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));

byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];

//copy binary contect to output stream
while(in.read(outputByte) != -1) {
    out.write(outputByte);
}

in.close();
out.close();
```

while creating the file, I am getting more records (not exact my records count which I given).

Please suggest to me to resolve this

Comment: Does `generateCsvFileBuffer` generate what you expected ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a String. This String can be converted to bytes. And you want to send these bytes to the response output stream.

Instead of using an InputStream over the byte array, reading chunks in loops, and writing each chunk in an incorrect way (The last chunk most probably doesn't have exactly 4096 bytes, and `read()` doesn't guarantee to read 4096 bytes: it could read less), just directly write the bytes to the output stream:

```
out.write(sb.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```